# Medical attendant visa for Sweden

Tags: schengen-visas, health, sweden

My sister is suffering for a medical condition which requires immense moral and physical support. She got ill while she was in Pakistan whereas her home is in Sweden. Now she has been declared fit to travel back to Sweden.
I want to apply for a Swedish visa, so I can visit her and assist her in going back to her normal tasks with her kids and job?
What exactly should be my supporting documents for this matter?
Also, if I attach a doctors letter stating her illness, what more information should the doctor provide to support my visa document?
I’m happily married with a kid and I'm a Pakistan resident.